# Random Perturbation of Data to get Training Data for Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am working on Soil Spectral Classification using neural networks and I have data from my Professor obtained from his lab which consists of spectral reflectance from wavelength 1200 nm to 2400 nm. He only has 270 samples.

I have been unable to train the network for accuracy more than 74% since the training data is very less (only 270 samples). I was concerned that my Matlab code is not correct, but when I used the Neural Net Toolbox in Matlab, I got the same results...nothing more than 75% accuracy.

When I talked to my Professor about it, he said that he does not have any more data, but asked me to do random perturbation on this data to obtain more data. I have research online about random perturbation of data, but have come up short.

Can someone point me in the right direction for performing random perturbation on 270 samples of data so that I can get more data?

Also, since by doing this, I will be constructing 'fake' data, I don't see how the neural network would be any better cos isn't the point of neural nets using actual real valid data to train the network?

Thanks,

Faisal.

Comment: One interesting side note that may also help you in the future when using Artificial Neural Networks:  If you are concerned that your implementation is buggy (i.e. "incorrect"), you can always check your algorithm by using finite difference approximation of the gradient (assuming you are training by error back-propagation and are using a discriminative objective function for a non-stochastic network).  You can simply use a few small toy cases (i.e. very small feature vectors) with a small model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think trying to fabricate more data is a bad idea: you can't create anything with higher information content than you already have, unless you know the true distribution of the data to sample from. If you did, however, you'd be able to classify with the [Bayes optimal error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bayes_optimal_classifier), which would be impossible to beat.

What I'd be looking at instead is whether you can alter the parameters of your neural net to improve performance. The thing that immediately springs to mind with small amounts of training data is your weight regulariser (are you even using regularised weights), which can be seen as a prior on the weights if you're that way inclined. I'd also look at altering the activation functions if you're using simple linear activations, and the number of hidden nodes in addition (with so few examples, I'd use very few, or even bypass the hidden layer entirely since it's hard to learn nonlinear interactions with limited data).

While I'd not normally recommend it, you should probably use cross-validation to set these hyper-parameters given the limited size, as you're going to get unhelpful insight from a 10-20% test set size. You might hold out 10-20% for final testing, however, so as to not bias the results in your favour.

Comment: Thanks, I am going the radial basis functions route. It is much more complicated and huge comparatively, but it does work. Thanks for suggestion to "alter" and try different things with the neural net.

Answer (score 3):

First, some general advice:

1. Normalize each input and output variable to [0.0, 1.0]
2. When using a feedforward MLP, try to use 2 or more hidden layers
3. Make sure your number of neurons per hidden layer is big enough, so the network is able to tackle the complexity of your data

It should always be possible to get to 100% accuracy on a training set if the complexity of your model is sufficient. But be careful, 100% training set accuracy does not necessarily mean that your model does perform well on unseen data (generalization performance).

Random perturbation of your data can improve generalization performance, if the perturbation you are adding occurs in practice (or at least similar perturbation). This works because this means teaching your network on how the data could look different but still belong to the given labels.

In the case of image classification, you could rotate, scale, noise, etc. the input image (the output stays the same, naturally). You will need to figure out what kind of perturbation could apply to your data. For some problems this is difficult or does not yield any improvement, so you need to try it out. If this does not work, it does not necessarily mean your implementation or data are broken.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestions. Can you point me out in the right direction where I can learn how to do random perturbation of data? A Google search on that topic leads me to data mining resources and I am not sure that is what I need. My data consists of soil reflectance for different wavelengths (216). So, I have 216 'features' or inputs. I was asked to perform random perturbation thrice so that instead of 270 training data samples, I would have 1000 samples to train the network. So, any advice on random perturbation of data in general? How does it work? Where do I learn about it?

Comment: Have a look at [this paper](http://www.work.caltech.edu/pub/Abu-Mostafa1990hints.pdf), it covers adding invariances to your inputs as mentioned above. The idea is that your inputs are generally distorted by some unknown "noise" function. In the case of images we know that typical distortions are to scale, add pixel noise, stretch, rotate, translate, etc. You need to analyze what kind of noise could be involved in your case, so you can try to model such functions manually and thus give your network hints.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to add random noise to your data would be to apply gaussian noise.

I suppose your measures have errors associated with them (a measure without errors has almost no meaning). For each measured value M+-DeltaM you can generate a new number with N(M,DeltaM), where n is the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

This will add new points as experimental noise from previous ones, and will add help take into account exprimental errors in the measures for the classification. I'm not sure however if it's possible to know in advance how helpful this will be !